# Problem with Reverse Engineering GVM light, possibly encoding issue

Tags: reverse-engineering, encoding

So I bought this GVM-560AS LED photography light on Amazon. It is a really good light for the job; but to control it remotely you have to download a really dodgy APK from the GVM website, a package which flagged red across the board on VirusTotal.com

So in the spirit of experimentation I loaded the control app onto the Android emulator and captured the packets it sent to the light over WiFi.

It is sending UDP messages to port `2525` on the broadcast address `192.168.4.255(/24)`,
When I replay these UDP messages with Python it has the desired effect in controlling the light.
The issue is that I can't make sense of the message generation mechanism, and enumerating the 65,000 potential states seems a little tedious.

The message to turn the light on is
`ffffffffffff20720d390dfa0800450000341213400040119e54c0a80402c0a804ff92b009dd00207e4934433534303930303230353730303030303130313338354230333030303000000000900000000000`

The message to turn the light off is
`ffffffffffff20720d390dfa080045000034f14040004011bf26c0a80402c0a804ff83ed09dd00208c0e3443353430393030323035373030303030313030323837417375620b5f6700000000900000000000`

The message to set the brightness to 11% at 3200K is
`ffffffffffff20720d390dfa0800450000340bb640004011a4b1c0a80402c0a804ffb4e809dd002046f03443353430393030323035373030303230313062463737310035002ff1ba00000000900000000000`

The message to set the brightness to 63% at 3200K is
`ffffffffffff20720d390dfa080045000034aee7400040110180c0a80402c0a804ff9cbf09dd002060163443353430393030323035373030303230313366383141360035002fd18cb003ff3f900000000000`

I am guessing that this is just a weird encoding scheme that I can't figure out, rather than it being some kind of proprietary RPC.
Any suggestions or pointers towards the generation mechanism would be much appreciated!

Comment: It would be helpful if you extracted the actual payload with wireshark. Then you would not have to put all the Ethernet/IP/UDP headers on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Mike76 This comes from having to feed Python's socket.socket the full UDP frame :(

```3443353430393030323035373030303 0 303130 3032383741``` Off
```3443353430393030323035373030303 0 303130 3133383542``` On
```3443353430393030323035373030303 2 303130 6246373731``` 11% @ 3200K
```3443353430393030323035373030303 2 303136 3436413338``` 99% @ 3200K


The spaces are not part of the payload, I have added them.

Comment: I also don't overly mind having the MAC addresses of the emulator and virtual NAT interface on the tinterwebz ^_^

Comment: Hi! I bought one of these, discovered the same dodgy APK, and started reverse-engineering the protocol as well.  I might try disassembling the APK to find some answers as to what's going on.

Comment: I've been struggling with this as well. I can send the OFF message, but that's about it. Has anyone made real progress here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first. After stripping the Ethernet / IP headers from your packets and interpreting the payload as an ASCII string, we come up with the following values:

`4C540900205700000100287A` ⟵ turn on
`4C540900205700000101385B` ⟵ turn off
`4C54090020570002010bF771` ⟵ set brightness to 11%
`4C54090020570002013f81A6` ⟵ set brightness to 63%

Next, I obtained a copy of the APK, extracted the DEX file, and disassembled it. Fortunately the code was not obfuscated and it was very easy to see how the values were being generated.

From what I can tell, the payload is a string consisting of the following components:

- The string `4C5409`
- The device ID (`00` in your case)
- The device type (`20` in your case)
- The string `57000`
- The command (1 character)
- The string `01`
- The parameter (2-4 characters)
- The CRC-16/XMODEM checksum*

** the checksum is computed by taking the concatenated value of the preceding components and interpreting it as hexadecimal byte values*

The parameters differ based on what command is being sent to the device:

`0` ⟶ set state (parameter is `00` for on and `01` for off - go figure)
`2` ⟶ set brightness (parameter is percentage of intensity; for example: `63`)
`4` ⟶ set temperature (parameter is temperature; for example: `4500`)